# Why Does Latex Consider My Overlaid Accented Title to be in Math Mode?

Tags: scaling

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{scalefnt,scalerel}

\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}
\definecolor{BrooklynBlue}{RGB}{33,41,88}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]% #1 = title
{\bgroup
  \Huge
  \sbox0{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{black}#1}}}%
  \sbox1{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\textbf{\color{Gold}#1}}}%
  \usebox0\llap{\raisebox{1.37pt}{\usebox1}}
\egroup}


% % % Compiled with Xelatex

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{pspicture}(-5,0)(5,5)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{BrooklynBlue}%

\psframe[fillcolor=BrooklynBlue,fillstyle=solid](-5,0)(5,5) %Used with colored frame 
\psframe[linecolor=BrooklynBlue](-5,0)(5,5)% draws frame in black.
%top and bottom center


\rput[tc](0,2.5){\mytitle{\selectfont\scalefont{0.8}{ \vstretch{1.2}{No Hay Caf{\'{e}} en el Men{\'{u}}}}}}
%\rput[tc](0,2.5){\mytitle{\selectfont\scalefont{0.8}{ \vstretch{1.2}{\textbf{No Hay Caf{\'{e}} en el Men{\'{u}}}}}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces (with an error):

[image]

However, when I comment out `\rput[tc](0,2.5){\mytitle{\selectfont\scalefont{0.8}{ \vstretch{1.2}{No Hay Caf{\'{e}} en el Men{\'{u}}}}}}` and replace it by `\rput[tc](0,2.5){\mytitle{\selectfont\scalefont{0.8}{ \vstretch{1.2}{\textbf{No Hay Caf{\'{e}} en el Men{\'{u}}}}}}}`---everything seems to work well:

[image]

QUESTION: Why does Latex consider the original title to be in math mode (and what can I do about it)? Then, when I simply insert a `\textbf` command, everything seems to be fine? I compile the code with `xelatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but trying to come up with a diagnosis of the situation. Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated? The reason I ask is that on my system (MacTeX2022, all updates applied) I get no output at all under XeLaTeX, while I am able to replicate the issues you describe under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for considering the problem. I'm not sure of the version, but it is not a MAC and it is definitely more than two years old. Ordinarily, I would think that would be the problem, but it seems you are able to replicate the problem with Lualatex, so I'm not sure what the cause may be.

Comment: probably not related but don't use box1 in that way. Also why use pstrcks here which adds lots of engine dependencies, it seems lke a standard ccolor box?

Comment: You can simplfy your example to `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\vstretch{1.2}{\frac\alpha\beta}
\end{document}` whch is set in math mode

Comment: that \vstretch handles its content in math mode is described in the first four lines of the scalerel documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer wow, never thought to look there:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The secrets of the documentation magic are only transmitted from mouth to ear of druid to druid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual of `scalerel` tells you that `\vstretch` typesets its argument in math mode.

But do you need `scalerel` to begin with?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}
\definecolor{BrooklynBlue}{RGB}{33,41,88}

\newcommand{\scaletitle}[2]{%
  \scalebox{0.8}[1.2]{\textcolor{#1}{\Huge\bfseries#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{%
  \rlap{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\scaletitle{black}{#1}}}%
  \raisebox{1.37pt}{\parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering\scaletitle{Gold}{#1}}}%
}


% % % Compiled with Xelatex

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{pspicture}(-5,0)(5,5)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{BrooklynBlue}

\psframe[fillcolor=BrooklynBlue,fillstyle=solid](-5,0)(5,5)% Used with colored frame 
\psframe[linecolor=BrooklynBlue](-5,0)(5,5)% draws frame in black.
%top and bottom center

\rput[tc](0,2.5){\mytitle{No Hay Caf\'{e} en el Men\'{u}}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. `Caf{\'{e}}` is wrong (unless you are dealing with text in a bib file)
2. handling the various settings with separate functions is better
3. no need for `\sbox`
4. compile with `xelatex-unsafe`

Comment: Many thanks egreg for this answer.